# ListView with custom adapter won't update when contents updates

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

I have one custom ListView called AreasListView which I've included in the XML file. The only things that differentiate this from a ListView are the following lines of code:

```
private void setFooter(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.areas_list_add_item, null);
    addFooterView(footer);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)
{
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The footer is added by the list itself in the constructor.

To this list I am setting a custom adapter in the onCreate method. Later on (when the user clicks on the footer that the custom list view has) another activity is started for result. When that one returns a new item is added to the ArrayList that sits under the custom adapter.

Here's the adapter code:

```
public class AreasAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

{

```
private Manager manager;

public AreasAdapter(Manager mgr){
    this.manager = mgr;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return manager.getAreas().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0)
{
    return manager.getAreas().get(arg0);
}

public Area getArea(int index){
    return manager.getAreas().get(index);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0)
{
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int arg0)
{
    return Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
{
    AreasListItem viewToReturn = null;
    if (arg1 != null){
        viewToReturn = (AreasListItem)arg1;
    } else {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) arg2.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewToReturn = (AreasListItem)inflater.inflate(R.layout.areas_list_item, null);
    }
    viewToReturn.setArea(manager.getAreas().get(arg0));
    return viewToReturn;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (manager.getAreas().size() == 0);
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0)
{
    super.registerDataSetObserver(arg0);
}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
{
          super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);

}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    return true;
}
```

}

After I receive the result I try to call notifyDataSetChanged, but it doesn't work. Code:

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Area resultArea = (Area) returnIntent.getExtras().get(ActivityAreaAdd.EXTRA_AREA);
                service.getManager().addArea(resultArea);
//              TODO figure out how to update the list with the newly added areas
                ((AreasAdapter)(((HeaderViewListAdapter) list.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I've tried the following so far:

- change AreasListView so that I don't get a HeaderListViewAdapter and try calling notifyDataSetChanged();
- call list.invalidate();
- call list.invalidateViews();
- call list.requestLayout();

---

UPDATE:
I tried using @Jack's solution and it doesn't work. Here's what I did:
from my onActivityResult:

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Area resultArea = (Area) returnIntent.getExtras().get(ActivityAreaAdd.EXTRA_AREA);
//              TODO figure out how to update the list with the newly added areas
                ((AreasAdapter)(((HeaderViewListAdapter) list.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter())).addArea(resultArea);
            }
```

and the corresponding code from AreasAdapter:

```
public void addArea(Area a){
    manager.addArea(a);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Is your result returning the correct result_code for RESULT_OK?

Comment: Yes. It is, I've been debugging it and it returns both the Area and RESULT_OK.

Comment: What is HeaderViewListAdapter?

Comment: The AreasList adds a footer to itself. Apparently ListView (which it extends) wraps its adapter with a HeaderViewList adapter when a header or footer is added to the list. I think it might be it that causes the problem, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Apparently what was needed was to remove the @Override setAdapter method from my custom list.

It is weird, since all it contained was a call to super.setAdapter(adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling :

```
list.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426) answer as I think it will point you in the right direction. He basically says:

> For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the
>   add, insert, remove, and clear functions on the Adapter.

EDIT: Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List8.html) snippet of code. They add the notifyDataSetChanged() call to the adapter:

```
       public void clearPhotos() {
            mPhotos.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addPhotos() {
            int whichPhoto = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (mPhotoPool.length - 1));
            int newPhoto = mPhotoPool[whichPhoto];
            mPhotos.add(newPhoto);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: How did you implement it? Are you now using the adapter to add items? Did it error out? Can you post exactly HOW you are adding items now (code example from other activity if need be).

Comment: from my onActivityResult: ((AreasAdapter)(((HeaderViewListAdapter) list.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter())).addArea(resultArea);

Comment: from AreasAdapter: public void addArea(Area a){
  manager.addArea(a);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

Comment: Please append your original question, it is difficult to decipher code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try list.requestLayout() it helped me with TextView and as in documentation

> "Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view"